# Javascript: Copy independent objects of different MIME types

Tags: javascript, clipboard, mime-types, clipboard.js

We have two HTML elements that we'd like to copy to the clipboard in our Javascript. They are of different types (TEXT, IMAGE). We want these objects to be pasted as individual, independent items when pasted into another application (eg, Powerpoint).

Everything we've tried results in a single item being pasted into the destination app.

Suggestions?

Comment: I guess, the solution can be quite different, depending on what specific application you have downstream

Comment: Aren't there standardized ways of copying multiple items to a clipboard for each OS? Regardless, our target application is Powerpoint. So, we want to click a button on a web page, copy two separate elements (of different MIME types), then have the ability to paste into Powerpoint and have two distinct, independent elements be pasted there.